# Is there a way to find out when the traffic on math.se is the heaviest?

Tags: feature-request, statistics

That's the question. Is there data that shows when the number of users at any given time of the day (say over a 1 hour period) is the most?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the traffic measured by the number of page views or by new posts added? The second you can probably find through a data.stackexchange query; not so sure about the first.

Comment: This is more-or-less in a similar spirit: [Depending on the tag is there a possibility to know on which days and hours are there more answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3865/depending-on-the-tag-is-there-a-possibility-to-know-on-which-days-and-hours-are)

Comment: May be of interest: [Is there a way to see how many users are currently active?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3618/19341)

Comment: There is analytics data only visible to moderators ([see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2543/statistics-of-questions/2544#2544) for example) but it does not go as finely-grained as hours; at most you could see the number of page views, visits, and new visits on any given day.

Comment: Related posts on [meta.se]: [How many SO users are online?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52720) and [View approximate number of users online](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2631).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Total number of posts (both questions and answers counted) [by hour of the day](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/57633/posts-by-hour-of-the-day). Note that [StackExchange servers operate on UTC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42179/what-time-zone-do-sos-servers-operate-in).

[image: posts by hour]

Number of posts by [hour and day of week](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/57632/posts-by-hour-and-day), also UTC.

[image: day of week]

Comment: If you want to know what the peak hours (1600-2100 UTC) are in your time zone: http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?iso=20130104T16&ah=5 :)

Comment: There are patterns there. Although not shown, I guess questions are mostly asked during working hours and answers are mostly posted off-work?